# Calling JavaScript function oncellchange

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am trying to call a JavaScript function `oncellchange`, but it's not working.
Any help / guidance is appreciated. Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function trainingcourses_paging(pageclickednumber, parameter)
{
 alert('working');
}            

</script>
        
<input type="text" name="date" id="date" 
 oncellchange="trainingcourses_paging('1','');" />
```

Comment: When should it trigger? Have you tried `onchange` instead?

Comment: was never aware of `oncellchange` I swear I learn so much from browsing SO

Comment: onCellChange was stupid IE event, use onChange instead. @Levi answer should work.

Comment: Neither it works with `onchange`. It should trigger when I put a value in it's text place.

Comment: onChange happens if the value has changed and then the input box loses focus. Does it not trigger the function if you press tab after typing into the text box?

Answer (score 1):

An input element has a onchange event, not an oncellchange, at least in all current major browsers. I believe oncellchange comes from an old version of IE only.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function trainingcourses_paging(pageclickednumber, parameter)
{
 alert('working');
}


</script>



<input type="text" name="date" id="date" 
 onchange="trainingcourses_paging('1','');" />
```